# What is the better to manage state in React Native project on Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, expo

I am creating React Native App for mobile on Expo.
When we try to make mobile Apps, we should usually manage state in this app.
However, I am using Expo. Of course, Expo is useful to start React Native App easily and quickly but sometimes Expo cannot accept modules.

So, in this case, I tried to use Realm to manage state but Expo can't follow this.

Could you teach me which way for state management is better in React Native on Expo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to go about this, two of which I know and have used:

`AsyncStorage`: This is default with `react-native` and you won't need to install anything to use it, here's a few tutorials and documentation on it.

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage
2. https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/what-is-asyncstorage-in-react-native-and-how-you-to-use-it-with-app-state-manager-1x09-b8c636ce5f6e
3. https://medium.com/@richardzhanguw/storing-and-retrieving-objects-using-asyncstorage-in-react-native-6bb1745fdcdd

`React-Redux`: This is something I use a lot more, it utilises `AsyncStorage` but allows you to create a better storage flow and a system of persisting data so when you close the app and reopen it, the data will still be there. I've found `React-Redux` to be a lot easier once properly learned, here's a few documentations on it.

1. http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/redux
2. https://alligator.io/react/react-native-redux/
3. https://medium.com/@relferreira/react-native-redux-react-navigation-ecec4014d648

A quick google search on either (`react native using react redux` or `react native using async storage`) will give you quite a few documentations/tutorials that is quite useful and you always have Stackoverflow, if you're ever stuck.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways

1. redux  (https://redux.js.org/)
2. mobx (https://mobx.js.org/intro/overview.html)
3. react context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

for small apps, i prefered use  react context and for an app with a large scale I using redux